# IOS doesn't receive first notification in background

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

IOS 13.7 IPhone Xr, Xcode Version 11.7 (11E801a)

I edited app scheme and set launch mode to "Wait for the executable to be launched". I run app, and send a simple notification on my device.

this notification:

```
{
"aps":{
    "content-available":1
      }
}
```

in xcode status changed from "Waiting to attach to test on iPhone" to "Running test on iPhone", but the notification wasn't received.

i try catch notification in this method:

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
```

Next notification I receive successfully. This case can be repeated after application reload.

Can you help me find out why I don't receive the first notification

Comment: The first one was caught by `didFinishLaunching`. You returned `true` so `didReceiveRemoteNotification` was not called.

Comment: @matt [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application#return_value)

The return value is ignored if the app is launched as a result of a remote notification

Comment: OK but what about the first sentence? The notification that launches the app arrives in `didFinishLaunching`...? Also, are you using a scene delegate? That changes everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app wasn’t running, the push notification is passed to your AppDelegate in the launchOptions

```
    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        ...
        let notificationOption = launchOptions?[.remoteNotification]
        if let notification = notificationOption as? [String:AnyObject]{
           // received notification
        }
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this payload :

{"aps":{"alert":"","content-available":1}}